# Optimization When Using CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, cte, query-performance

I want to take aggregate data for each sales person employed and display the `Salesname`, `saleamount`, and `saleshippingamount`.  I have the query set to use 2 `UPDATE` CTE statements to update a table that house the master data for each employee. I am updating because I need aggregate totals to be displayed.

The syntax takes roughly 10 minutes to complete and between the two tables there are roughly 60,000 rows to process.  Is a CTE The wrong way to go about this?

Below is sample DDL. The employee names are populated from the HR table, but I did not show DDL for this, just an insert statement.

```
Create Table #FinalData
(
    employee varchar(400)
    ,tr float
    ,tf float
)
Create Table #TR
(
    employee varchar(400)
    ,saleamount float
    ,saledate date
)
Create Table #TF
(
    employee varchar(400)
    ,saleshippingamt float
    ,saledate date
)
INSERT INTO #TR (employee, saleamount, saledate) VALUES
('Employee 1', '12.63', '2017-01-01'), ('Employee 1', '15.00' ,'2017-01-02')
,('Employee 2', '14.00', '2017-01-03'), ('Employee 2' ,'12.00', '2017-01-03')
,('Employee 3', '16.00', '2017-01-03'), ('Employee 3', '13.00', '2017-01-04')
INSERT INTO #TF (employee, saleshippingamt, saledate) VALUES
('Employee 1', '5.00', '2017-01-01'), ('Employee 1', '6.00' ,'2017-01-02')
,('Employee 2', '5.50', '2017-01-03'), ('Employee 2' ,'5.00', '2017-01-03')
,('Employee 3', '6.00', '2017-01-03'), ('Employee 3', '6.00', '2017-01-04')
INSERT INTO #FINALDATA (employee) Values
('Employee 1'), ('Employee 2'), ('Employee 3')

;With TR As 
(
    SELECT 
    employee
    ,SUM(saleamount) Totals
    FROM #TR
    WHERE saledate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-25'
    GROUP BY employee
)
UPDATE t
SET tr = t2.TotalCount
FROM #FinalData t
INNER JOIN (Select employee, SUM(Totals) TotalCount
            FROM TR
            GROUP BY employee) As t2
ON t.employee = t2.employee

;With TF As 
(
    SELECT 
    employee
    ,SUM(saleshippingamt) Totals
    FROM #TF
    WHERE saledate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-25'
    GROUP BY employee
)
UPDATE t
SET tf = t2.TotalCount
FROM #FinalData t
INNER JOIN (Select employee, SUM(Totals) TotalCount
            FROM TF
            GROUP BY employee) As t2
ON t.employee = t2.employee

Select * FROM #FinalData
```

And this is my [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByMKCJNyW).

What is an option that I have to optimize this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally been able to do some testing and playing with the query and can give you more concrete suggestions.  I used AdventureWorks for my sample so I had some actual data to work with.

#### Option 1 - Add Indexes

This will give you the best performance increase for the least amount of effort.  I saw an increase of 40% in query execution in my sample set just by adding three indexes.

Tables `#TR` and `#TF`. Add an index on the `saledate`, `employee`, and include the amount.

```
CREATE INDEX IDXNC_TFSaleDateEmployee ON #TF (saledate, employee) INCLUDE (saleshippingamt)

CREATE INDEX IDXNC_TRSaleDateEmployee ON #TR (saledate, employee) INCLUDE (saleamount)
```

for the `#FinalData`, you should have a clustered index on the `employee` field.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDXC_FinalDataEmployee ON #FinalData (employee)
```

#### Option 2 - Change your query

Your query could use some tweaking, it may even allow you to get rid of the temp table all together.

This query also performs a little faster, but the indexes will give you the best increase in performance.

```
;WITH CTE_Employee AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT employee
    FROM (
        SELECT employee
        FROM #TR
        UNION ALL
        SELECT employee
        FROM #TF
        ) AS D
    )
    , CTE_TR AS
    (
    SELECT employee
        , SUM(saleamount) AS TotalDue
    FROM #TR
    WHERE saledate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-25'
    GROUP BY employee
    )
    , CTE_TF AS
    (
    SELECT employee
        , SUM(saleamount) AS TotalDue
    FROM #TR
    WHERE saledate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-25'
    GROUP BY employee
    )

SELECT S.employee
    , TR.TotalDue
    , TF.TotalDue
FROM CTE_Employee AS S
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_TR AS TR ON TR.employee = S.employee
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_TF AS TF ON TF.employee = S.employee
```

#### General Comments

You can name CTEs however you like, but it does confuse things a little bit if you give them the same name as the table they represent.  I like to give them a `CTE_*` prefix, but it's optional.

You can also chain CTEs as I've done here.

In your original query, you were doing two aggregate operations when you were getting the totals for the `totalcount` in the `#FinalData`. That would also be something to keep an eye out for, you can see that it's unnecessary, but SQL will do the sort and sum operation multiple times.  You could just join the CTE table on instead of doing a sub-select.

*You Had*

```
UPDATE t
SET tf = t2.TotalCount
FROM #FinalData t
INNER JOIN (Select employee, SUM(Totals) TotalCount
            FROM TF
            GROUP BY employee) As t2
ON t.employee = t2.employee
```

*Should be*

```
UPDATE t
SET tf = t2.TotalCount
FROM #FinalData t
INNER JOIN TF As t2 ON t.employee = t2.employee
```

Answer (score 0):

Post dummy data but always post your real table structure.This help in getting the real view.
for Example I don't think #FinalData with emloyee varchar(400) is real.

IMHO,Creating CI or any index on varchar(400) is so bad that it will never give you Index benefits.

varchar(400)  are best for covering index only.

So if really I have such situation in real life then I will only concentrate in writing best possible optimize query .
And may be apply paging etc to get faster result.

I won't create index on such situation.

So as per data and structire posted by you.Use variable instead of hard coded.

If inner join not working then go for left join

```
select fd.employee
,tr.Totals
 ,tf.shippingamtTotals
 from 
#FinalData FD
inner JOIN
(
 SELECT 
    employee
    ,SUM(saleamount) Totals
    FROM #TR
    WHERE saledate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-25'
    GROUP BY employee
)tr
on fd.employee=tr.employee
inner join

(
SELECT 
    employee
    ,SUM(saleshippingamt) shippingamtTotals
    FROM #TF
    WHERE saledate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-25'
    GROUP BY employee
)tf
on fd.employee=tf.employee
```